# Why can't I send items to Trash even though Trash is empty?

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, trash

I usually delete files permanently using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.

But once I accidentally sent an item to the Trash can using just <kbd>Delete</kbd> and got this error:

```
"Trash can touched maximum limit/Empty Trash can manually".
```

But when I view the contents of the Trash can, it appears that it is actually empty: no files, no hidden files and no used space.

My OS is Kubuntu 12.04.1 LTS.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/288513/cant-move-files-to-the-trash

Comment: Ianhu how is that question related to mine? Also 1.I got my answer already, 2.That question is also newer than mine so my question is not in no way a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notice is based on the `metadata` file and not the actual content of the trash folder. Check for this file for the cache size (if you want):

`~/.local/share/Trash/metadata`

2 methods of getting rid of the notice:

- Remove it and the system will create a new file when you delete a file as a user.
- You can also edit the file and change `size={number}` to `size=0`

Comment: I don't see `metadata` in `~/.local/share/Trash`. I see just three subfolders: `info`, `files`, and `expunged`. Is `metadata` specific to Kubuntu? I'm on Lubuntu 12.10.

Comment: @vasa1 gnome and kde. not sure about lubuntu.

Comment: @Rinzwind, do you think it's worth making a separate question on this?

Comment: if you do make the Q as thorough as possible and include a reference to this topic as not working for you so it does not get closed as a dupe. @vasa1 I only see this msg icm with kde so it could be something else.

Comment: @Rinzwind, I think I'll hold off because I don't have any problems with Trash as yet but I was just curious.

Comment: @Rinzwind, please take a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/246888/25656): poster hasn't specified the OS, but also has `expunged`, `files` and `info`.