# Can't move files to the trash

Tags: nautilus

When I want to move a file to the Trash, Nautilus give me an message saying this:

> You can't move *example.file* to the trash can. Do you want to remove it immediately?

I can give you this photo but it's in Spanish

[image]

Comment: It's this file in a remote drive? Those types of drives does not support Trash. Some removable storage also does not support Trash.

Comment: @lie-ryan The files I tried to remove are in my home folder.

Comment: I've just ran into this because I mounted an extra drive on /home/.../.local (for Steam games).  Apparently Nautilus expects to be able to rename the file into the Trash folder.

Comment: See also [can't move files to trash without any permission issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614752/cant-move-files-to-trash-without-any-permission-issues?rq=1) for a different solution - a bug causing this in special cases.

Comment: This message also occurs if the file is too large for the trash

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I had the same problem and found out that the trash had the wrong owner. So I deleted the trash folder and made a new one.

Steps:

1. `cd ~/.local/share`
2. `ls -ld Trash`
3. Now you have to look if it has the right owner.
4. If the owner is `root` - delete the folder with: `sudo rm -r Trash`
5. `mkdir -m 700 Trash`

Hope I could help and that it solved your problem, because it did for me.

Comment: Instead of deleting `sudo chown -R $USER: Trash` as mentioned in the other answer should work as well to get the owner right...

Comment: I do not understand why this would happen on a fresh install of gnome 16.04.1 .  Something is wrong..  But thanks .. this worked.  Plus one given

Comment: on `Linux Mint` worked for me .

Answer (score 20):

As mentioned by *kr4utz* your problem is that Trash is owned by root.

A better way of changing the ownership without deleting the Trash folder would be to use the `chown` command from a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T):

```sh
sudo chown -R "$USER" ~/.local/share/Trash
```

That will change the owner from root to yourself without deleting your `Trash` folder.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to do so recursively (with the -R option)?

Comment: I had to "chown -R..." in order for this to work (to get at the inner files and info directories)

Answer (score 6):

That's what worked for me, if the files that refuse to delete are on a partition which is not formatted as `ext*`:

Open `/etc/fstab` in any editor as root (e.g. using `sudo nano /etc/fstab`).

There add in the line of the partition you have problems the option `uid=1000` (if your user ID is 1000, else change it)

Example:

```
/dev/sdb2   /media/scambio      vfat    rw,utf8,umask=0,uid=1000    0     0
```

and reboot

Comment: How do you reach **that** conclusion?

Comment: That's a suggestion I found on the Italian Ubuntu forum. I looked into the problem deeper some time ago for a different computer and that time it worked, so I re-searched the site and reapplied it last week on this computer with an analogous problem. It seems to be a problem of the read-write permission given via fstab if I remember well, You might find something about it in the fstab-wiki.

Comment: It seems to be a problem of the ownership of the mount and of the read-write permission (rwx) given via fstab . The, in my case, missing uid=1000 seemed to garble the ownership and prevented the normal file deleting. I'm no expert, but see:  (http://askubuntu.com/questions/113733/how-do-i-correctly-mount-a-ntfs-partition-in-etc-fstab)

Comment: Don't forget to create a folder named `.Trash-1000` in the root of that drive, if it doesn't exist already

Answer (score 0):

I found other solution that works for me. I had the folder Trash where the owner was root.

I delete the folder *Trash* like root user, you can do it directly from terminal with the correct command or like I did, I enter in the terminal the command:`sudo nautilus`, this open the nautilus like root user, I look for the folder Trash (`.local/share/Trash`) and I delete it (`like root user`) and after this I close the nautilus. I opened again the nautilus but like username (I mean normally), I delete some file and this automatically creates a folder Trash where the ownership now was my username.

Sorry for my english

Answer (score -3):

I have tried all above solutions but they didn't worked for me. Then I just gave all the permissions to Trash folder and it worked. Follow the below steps-

Step 1: `Open Terminal.`

Step 2: Run the command- `cd /home/username/.local/share`

Note that you have to replace "username" with your username eg. for me it is-   `cd /home/willson/.local/share`

Step 3: Give all the permissions to Trash folder using Command-

`sudo chmod -R 700 Trash/`

Now your deleted files will move to Trash.

Comment: **Please don't recommend `0777` a.k.a. “please-hack-my-system-and-destroy-my-data” permissions for no apparent reason!** There's almost never a reason to to that because it can be avoided with more sensible modifications like changing (group) ownership. -1

Answer (score -3):

For me, it was that partition was mounted in a folder owned by root and others didn't have write permissions

```
drwxr-xr-x 22 root    root    4096 Sep 17 01:31 data
```

So the trash folder could not be created in the top folder

I just changed the permissions of the folder were the partition is mounted.... and voila, it worked!!!!

```
sudo chmod 777 data
```

Comment: **Please don't recommend `0777` a.k.a. “please-hack-my-system-and-destroy-my-data” permissions for no apparent reason!** There's almost never a reason to to that because it can be avoided with more sensible modifications like changing (group) ownership. In this case a *sticky* folder, i. e. `1777` permissions, would be an acceptable solution for home use. -1