# Cannot move files to trash

Tags: nautilus, trash

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04, and getting a bug where I can't move files to the trash. When I go to delete something it says file "can't be put in the trash. Do you want to delete it immediately?"
I tried the instructions here: [Can't move files to the trash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/288513/cant-move-files-to-the-trash) but it didn't work. Not sure why this happened with the upgrade.
Any help much appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't move files to the trash](http://askubuntu.com/questions/288513/cant-move-files-to-the-trash)

Answer (score 4):

The OP posted:

> Solution:
>
> ```
> sudo nautilus
> ```
>
> Go into `.local/share` and delete the Trash folder. Make a new folder
>   and name it Trash, then go into terminal and do this:
>
> ```
> cd ~/.local/share
> sudo chown username:username Trash
> ```
>
> where `username` is your own username.
>
> I have no idea why it doesn't work unless you remake the trash folder,
>   but this way worked for me. Good luck if anyone else gets this bug!

Comment: @bobleponge314 Your answer is still to similar with one from the duplicate question: [this one](http://askubuntu.com/a/298335/147044).

Comment: Should I be bothered by the fact that I was able to remove and recreate the folder "Trash" without sudo?

Comment: @Nearoo That's ok, `~/.local/share` is in your home directory and owned by you,.