# Move to trash in nautilus doesn't work, trash folder stays empty

Tags: nautilus, delete, trash

When I click "move to trash" in the right-click context menu of nautilus, I get the following error:

```
"name of the file ” can't be put in the trash. Do you want to delete it immediately?
```

but I don't want to delete it permanently,and also the **restore** and empty buttons in the trash folder is **inactive**. My trash folder is always empty. How can I change the settings of trash?

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: What is the file name that you want to delete? try to delete another file and see if you get the same error.

Comment: Have you tried this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/288513/cant-move-files-to-the-trash

Comment: @KasiyA ,it doesn't any different.for every file it is the same

Comment: Did you try [Can't move files to the trash](http://askubuntu.com/questions/288513/cant-move-files-to-the-trash)? any changes?

Comment: @Muzaffar.thank you very much ,it solved my problem ,@KasiyA thank you too.